# MySQL Create Trigger Syntax Error near END

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

When I try and run my table/trigger creation script, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 19: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET NEW.fines_remaining = NEW.total_fines;
            END IF;
    END' at line 5
```

The following is the CREATE TRIGGER code which is causing the error:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER fines_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON student
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            IF TUPLE.fines_remaining > TUPLE.total_fines
                    SET NEW.fines_remaining = NEW.total_fines;
            END IF;
    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, I feel like the syntax is fine, but it's obviously not since there's some error being thrown.

EDIT: Immediately after posting this I notice that I still have these TUPLE 'variables' that I was using before I figured out about 'OLD' and 'NEW'.  I'm changing them and will update momentarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `then` after the if condition

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER fines_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON student
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            IF new.fines_remaining > old.total_fines then
                    SET NEW.fines_remaining = NEW.total_fines;
            END IF;
    END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Also I have changed `TUPLE` with new and old in the above trigger, you may need to adjust the logic as per your need.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm still new to SQL so I miss stuff like this.  Usually I can find it after a while but I was looking in the wrong places the whole time